# Arithmetic operation on the value returned by Solve

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I want to modify the value that is returned by Solve. Example:

```
SolC1 = Solve[Sin[ π x / L] == 1, x]
{{x -> L/2}}
```

I need to add n to x so that x becomes `n + L/2`.
Both of the following I tried yields unwanted result in the succeeding calculation.

```
SolC1 = (x -> L/2) + n
----
SolC1 = SolC1 + n
```

I particularly need the proper way to do this because `x` can have other variables depending on other `Solve` execution.

Comment: Look carefully at your expectation since there should be `2n` instead of `n` (`Sin` has a period `2 Pi`). My answer gives a recommended way to tackle your problem.

Comment: It's recommended to start your own symbol names with a lowercase letter. MMA's internal symbols always start with an uppercase letter, and this way you'll avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using

```
x + n /. First[SolC1]

(* ==> L/2 + n *)
```

If you need a new [rule](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) as the result, then you can do

```
x -> (x + n /. First[SolC1])
```

Comment: @Artes *Wrong* is a little harsh in this context, isn't it?  `ReplaceAll` is *the* standard way to substitute in variables, it's what a newcomer will learn first.  I assume by "wrong" you mean that `Solve` didn't return the full solution set, but considering that this was not the focus of the question, and the asker seems to be a beginner, jumping right into complex details that are not the focus of the question is not very educational.

Comment: Yes, it is.  I meant only `L/2 + n` is not a correct solution. I like `/.` but one can do silly mistakes with it e.g. replacing values returned by `Solve`.

Answer (score 5):

By default `Solve` returns generic solutions, nevertheless one can make use  of its new options (in `ver. 8`) to make it return all solutions in an appropriate form :

- `MaxExtraConditions` - additional (all) solutions can be returned specifying nondefault settings of `MaxExtraConditions` (default `...-> 0`), determining how many equations/conditions on parameters are allowed.
- `GeneratedParameters` (this option had been since `ver. 5` in other functions (e.g. in `Reduce`) but in `Solve` it hadn't worked before `ver. 8`) to specify names of parameters of the solutions.

#### Solution in Mathematica 8

In our case we need `MaxExtraConditions -> All` and `GeneratedParameters -> n`:

```
Solve[ Sin[(π x)/L] == 1, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All, GeneratedParameters -> n]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> ConditionalExpression[(L (π /2 + 2 π  n[1]))/π , n[1] ∈ Integers && L != 0]}}
> ```

`ConditionalExpression` (also new in `ver. 8`) is an adequate function since this expression is a solution if and only if `n[1]` is an integer number and `L != 0`. Nevertheless if we know that these conditions are true, then
`ConditionalExpression` can be simplified under an adequate assumption (the second argument of `Simplify`) like e.g. `Simplify[ %, n[1] ∈ Integers && L != 0]`.

It would be more convenient if we did not specify parameters in the assumption but used directly the output of `Solve` in `Simplify`. We can do it by taking an appropriate part of the result of `Solve`, therefore our preferred solution is the following :

```
Solve[ Sin[(π x)/L] == 1, x, GeneratedParameters -> n, MaxExtraConditions -> All] //
Simplify[#, #[[1, 1, 2, 2]]] &
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1/2 L (1 + 4 n[1])}}
> ```

**Edit**

#### Equivalent result in Mathematica 7

In `Mathematica 7` we couldn't use `GeneratedParameters` nor `MaxExtraConditions` in  `Solve`. Nevertheless we could make (for fun) the output of `Reduce` similar to that of `Solve` in `M 8`.   In this specific case an analogical expresion to `ConditionalExpression` is returned e.g. by

```
If @@ {And @@ Most @ #, Rule @@ Last @ #}& [
                 List @@ Reduce[ Sin[(π x)/L] == 1, x, GeneratedParameters -> n] ]
```

> ```
>  If[n[1] ∈  Integers && L != 0, x -> (L (π/2 + 2 π n[1]))/π]
> ```

and to get an appropriately simplified expression we can do e.g.

```
{{ Simplify[ #, #[[1]] ] &[ If @@ {And @@ Most @ #, Rule @@ Last @ #} &[
      List @@ Reduce[ Sin[(π x)/L] == 1, x, GeneratedParameters -> n]  ] ] }}
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1/2 L (1 + 4 n[1])}}
> ```

Making any replacements (as in other answers) in the output of `Solve` can be quite arbitrary and therefore it is not very convenient, nevertheless that way would provide simpler method to modify the output, on the other hand as stated before, in general `Solve` could not return all solutions in `ver. 7`.

Comment: +1 for better follow-up (I don't have time now to test though)

Comment: @IsaacS Thanks, it works in `M 8`, one could do something analogical  to make it work in `M 7` with `Reduce` though

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
Solve[Sin[ π x / L] == 1, x]

% /. (x -> z_) :> (x -> z + n)
```

> ```
> {{x -> L/2}}
>
> {{x -> L/2 + n}}
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this method often yields incorrect results as it does here. I upvoted your answer for a nicer approach than that in accepted one, however you should improve it. See other comments.

Comment: @Artes I'm sorry, I don't understand.  The OP wanted `n + L/2` and this returns `L/2 + n` -- how is that wrong?

Comment: He really wanted a general solution which should be `x -> L/2 + 2n` instead of `x -> L/2 + n` where `n` is integer.

Comment: @Artes I read the question again and I'm still not seeing that; have you talked to IsaacS?  A new question should be posted if he wants something different.

Comment: Yes he wanted `n` but he shouldn't, he should rather `2 n`, because it should be a solution.  He solves `Sin[ π x / L] == 1` and for odd `n` that is not a solution.

Comment: @Artes I see your point but that's not what was asked.  Given the age of this question a *new* question should be posted if that is the intent.

Comment: I'm surprised because of the resistance of the matter.  I'm giving up improving though I'm right with the remarks above.

Comment: @Artes I would welcome you posting a new question and answering it yourself.  It's not your fault that the OP asked the wrong question, however it's not *my* fault for answering that question.