# Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)

Tags: equation-solving, assignment, faq

I understand Mathematica can't assign the results of a Solve to the unknowns because there may be more than 1 solution. How can I assign the 4 values of following result to variables?

[image]

```
Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? In principle you can use `Replace` (or `Part`) to assign the values to variables.

Comment: @sebhofer - I want to assign the first x value to a variable X1, then the y value to Y1, the other two to X2 and Y2. I just don't seem to get the hang of references yet.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this :

```
s = Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}];
xx = s[[All, 1, 2]];
yy = s[[All, 2, 2]];
```

Now you can access solutions, this way `xx[[1]]`, `yy[[2]]`.

If you prefer to collect solutions in `Array`, there is another way :

```
X = Array[ x, {Length@s}];
Y = Array[ y, {Length@s}];
x[k_] /; MemberQ[ Range[ Length @ s], k] := s[[k, 1, 2]]
y[k_] /; MemberQ[ Range[ Length @ s], k] := s[[k, 2, 2]]
```

now  `X` is equivalent to `s[[All, 1, 2]]`, while `Y` to `s[[All, 2, 2]]`, e.g. :

```
X[[1]] == x[1]
Y == s[[All, 2, 2]]
```

> ```
> True
> True
> ```

You do not have to use or even to define `X` and `Y` arrays, 
e.g.

```
{x[1], y[1]}
```

> ```
> {(-11181 - Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 1/386 (13 - Sqrt[2242057])}
> ```

We've used `Condition` i.e. `/;` to assure definitions of `x[i], y[i]` only for `i` in an appropriate range determined by `Length @ s`, i.e. number of solutions.

Comment: I think the OP is a complete beginner, and all he's looking for is `ReplaceAll`.  This might be a bit too advanced for someone new to Mma.

Comment: @Szabolcs Literally there is the `assignment` tag, so he is rather looking for `Set` or `SetDelayed` applications.

Comment: I think I'll use your first solution for now, until I get the hang of ReplaceAll. @Szabolcs: Yes, Mma virgin. Thanks, all.

Comment: @stevenvh I think this answer can be also interesting for you : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/arithmetic-operation-on-the-value-returned-by-solve/8223#8223

Comment: @Artes: could you tell me how can I find more information about the function s[[All, 1, 2]]?

Comment: @anhnha That's all information you can get, unless you've defined s in a different way, however one can use `FullForm[s]`.

Comment: @Artes: What is the meaning of "All, 1, 2"  in that function?

Comment: @anhnha  Read the doccumentation pages of `Part` then you'll understand what such a notation  as `[[i,j,k]]` mean.

Comment: This works exactly as I hoped. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Usually you don't want to actually assign values to `x` and `y`, and you would use replacement rules instead:

```
sols = Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}];

{x, y} /. sols[[1]]
```

or for the second solution:

```
{x, y} /. sols[[2]]
```

---

If you *really* want to assign values to `x` and `y` globally, you could use:

```
Set @@@ sols[[1]]
```

but you *must* clear `x` and `y` before using another set:

```
Clear[x, y]
Set @@@ sols[[2]]
```

---

If you want to assign values to `x` and `y` within a `Block` you could do something like this:

```
Hold @@ {sols[[2]]} /. Rule -> Set /. _[vars_] :>
  Block[vars,
   Sin[x] + Sqrt[y] // N
  ]
```

This uses what I am calling the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) to get the values into `Block` in the right syntax without it prematurely evaluating.

---

Related questions:

[Getting rid of the “x ->” in FindInstance results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616091/mathematica-getting-rid-of-the-x-in-findinstance-results)

[Using the output of Solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355218/using-the-output-of-solve)

Comment: +1.Something [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234701/how-to-block-symbols-without-evaluating-them/6236264#6236264) to your last comment and the injector pattern.

Comment: I agree that often you just want to use rules, but in my case I'm trying to set a global variable before going on to solve for other things (where `Solve` will work better if it has this global value instead of trying to remain general for all possible values). I tried the equivalent of `Set[sols[[1]]]`, and when that didn't work. Of course the "help" file is no help because it insists on explaining the symbol `=` and not the function `Set`, so I ended up here. What is `Set @@@ sols[[1]]` doing?

Comment: @Travis Assuming you want this in my own words please reference [(46248)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46248/121).  `@@@` is shorthand for `Apply` at *levelspec* `{1}`.  So `foo @@@ {x -> val1, y -> val2}` becomes `{foo[x, val1], foo[y, val2]}`, or in the code in the question `{Set[x, val1], Set[y, val2]}`, which then assigns the values with `Set`.  (`=` is the shorthand for `Set`.)

Comment: I understand that `Set` and `=` are equivalent, but it's the `Set[x, val]` that the help file wouldn't tell me. I'm not sure what *levelspec* is, but I see that `@@@` is grabbing stuff from either side of `->`. I'm guessing there's some `Func[x, val]` equivalent to `x -> val` so that `@@@` replaces `Func` with `Set`?

Comment: @Travis Okay.  You need to become familiar with the long form of all these "shorthand" operators.  You can see the long form by wrapping `code` in `HoldForm[FullForm[  code  ]]` -- for example `HoldForm[FullForm[  {x -> val1, y = val2}  ]]` will reveal `List[Rule[x, val1], Set[y, val2]]`.  This "FullForm" expression is what you need to visualize when you think about *Mathematica* manipulating code.  Virtually all `Replace`, `Map`, `Apply`, `Part`, etc. operations effectively "see" this structure, not the short form you type in.  See e.g. `HoldForm[FullForm[  a - b  ]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your comments have been very helpful, and I keep coming back here to relearn "what function was that, that showed me the structure?" I've been searching **levelspec**, but I only find references *to* it, and to tutorials *on* it directly. I have questions such as "Does the index start counting at 0 or 1? Does it count up or down? Is it relative or absolute?" --- Do you know a good tutorial or reference you can point me and others to?

Comment: @Travis the canonical Q&A here is [(15567)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121), and I suggest you also look at the links in my answer to [(29750)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121).  If these do not answer all your questions please let me know.

Answer (score 21):

**Update:** Version 10 built-in function [Values](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html?q=Values) does value extraction conveniently for rules appearing in lists of arbitrary lengths and depths:

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = Values[Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}]]
(* {{(-11181-Sqrt[2242057])/74498,1/386 (13-Sqrt[2242057])}, 
    {(-11181+Sqrt[2242057])/74498,1/386 (13+Sqrt[2242057])}} *)
```

Another example:

```
lst={{a->1,b->2},{c->3},{{d->4}},{e->5,{f->6,{g->7}}}};
Values[lst]
(* {{1,2},{3},{{4}},{5,{6,{7}}}} *)
```

---

**Original post:**

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}][[All, All, -1]]
(* {{(-11181 - Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 1/386 (13 - Sqrt[2242057])}, 
    {(-11181 + Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 1/386 (13 + Sqrt[2242057])}} *)

{x1, y2}
(* {(-11181- Sqrt[2242057]) / 74498, 1 / 386 (13 + Sqrt[2242057])} *)
```

Comment: I'm sorry you've deleted your previous answer nevertheless suppresing duplicates we reduce increasing overall entropy of this site, +1.

Comment: @artes, thank you for the upvote. I agree with your concern over excessive duplicates. The other Q/A is indeed a special case of this one. However, because of its special structure, some tricks that work there do not work here, e.g `Last@@@Solve[...]`.

Answer (score 10):

If you really wish to assign solutions to variables, you can do something like this:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[Subscript]
sols=Solve[y^2==13x+17&&y==193x+29,{x,y}];
i=0;
sols/.{r__Rule}:>Set@@@({r}/.var:x|y->Subscript[var,++i]);
Subscript//Definition
```

> Out[5]=
>
> Subscript[x,1]=(-11181-Sqrt[2242057])/74498
>   Subscript[x,2]=(-11181+Sqrt[2242057])/74498
>   Subscript[y,1]=1/386(13-Sqrt[2242057])
>   Subscript[y,2]=1/386 (13+Sqrt[2242057])

Then you can use the solutions for demonstration purposes:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's a painless solution:

```
s = Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}];
```

Assign the four results of the solution s above to a variable each, in sequence

```
{X1, Y1, X2, Y2} = s // Values // Flatten;
```

Verify

```
{X1, Y1, X2, Y2}
```

> ```
> {(-11181 - Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 1/386 (13 - Sqrt[2242057]), 
>  (-11181 + Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 1/386 (13 + Sqrt[2242057])}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Ah, they finally implemented it in version 10, then!
Here's a procedure I've been using since version 5, it might provide similar features in versions prior to the introduction of Value.
(I'm not sure, but maybe I posted it on the MathGroup... so forgive me if this is not news)

I had called it "ToValues". I gave it two options:

> ```
> Options[ToValues] = {
>       Flattening -> Automatic, IndexedFunction -> False};
> ```

The help message is hopefully self-explicating:

> ```
> ToValues::usage =
>     "ToValues[li] 
>     suppresses the Rule wrapper in every part of list li.\n ToValues[li,F] \
> applies the function F to every rhs of Rule, turning var->value into \
> F[value]. If the function F has a parametrized head, then it is possible to \
> pass the lhs of Rule to it by setting the option IndexedFunction->True. It will \
> turn var->value into F[var][value].\n When the option Flattening is set to \
> Automatic, ToValues flattens li to yield a simplified structure (the \
> flattening is tuned to get the simplest list of values for the solution of a \
> system of several equation in several variables). With Flattening set to None \
> the original structure is left intact.";
> ```

The code is really short.

> ```
> ToValues[li_, opts___Rule] := Module[
>     {newli, vars, sols, fl},
>     fl = Flattening /. {opts} /. Options[ToValues];
>     sols = First[Dimensions[li]]; vars = Last[Dimensions[li]];
>     newli = li /. Rule[_, v_] -> v;
>     If[fl == Automatic && vars == 1, newli = Flatten[newli]];
>     If[fl == Automatic && sols == 1, First[newli], newli]
>     ]
>
> ToValues[li_, fun_, opts___Rule] := 
>   Module[
>     {newli, vars, sols, foo, fl, mi},
>     mi = IndexedFunction /. {opts} /. Options[ToValues];
>     fl = Flattening /. {opts} /. Options[ToValues];
>     If[mi == True,
>           newli = li /. (x_ -> v_) -> foo[x][v],
>           newli = li /. (_ -> v_) -> foo[v]
>       ];
>     sols = First[Dimensions[li]]; vars = Last[Dimensions[li]];
>     If[fl == Automatic && vars == 1, newli = Flatten[newli]];
>     If[fl == Automatic && sols == 1, First[newli], newli] //. foo -> fun
> ]
> ```

Example data:

```
sols = {{x -> 1}, {y -> 2}, {z -> 3}};
```

Application of ToValues to lists of rules produces a list of values

```
ToValues[sols] // InputForm
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Of course assignment is immediate, here

```
{x1,x2,x3} = ToValues[sols]
```

By default, ToValues returns the simplest list of values possible, suppressing nested list. If you want to preserve the original nesting, this is what the Flattening option does:

```
ToValues[sols, Flattening -> None] // InputForm
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3}}

We can specify a function to be applied to the returned values.

```
ToValues[sols, F] // InputForm
```

> {F[1], F[2], F[3]}

We can also use function that make use of the right hand sides of the rules. Just define them as functions with a parametrized Head and set IndexedFunction->True to instruct ToValues to make use of that. In this case we want to return lists in the form {variable name, variable value}:

```
F[var_][value_] := {var, value}

ToValues[sols, F, IndexedFunction -> True] // InputForm
```

> {{x, 1}, {y, 2}, {z, 3}}

```
ToValues[sols, F, IndexedFunction -> True, Flattening -> None] // InputForm
```

> {{{x, 1}}, {{y, 2}}, {{z, 3}}}

**Real world applications**

ToValues is normally used to extract solutions from the lists returned by Solve, NSolve, DSolve, etc. In its default form it can be applied in this way:

```
Solve[{x + y == 1, x - y == 2}] // ToValues
```

> {3/2, 1/2}

This gives a list of the complex solutions

```
Solve[x^5 == 1] // ToValues
```

This uses the optional function to compute the real and imaginary part of each solution

```
coords = ToValues[Solve[x^5 == 1, x], {Re[#], Im[#]} &] // N;
ListPlot[coords, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[.018]];
```

And this pushes the function to create graphics objects (Points) based on those values inside ToValues:

```
pts = ToValues[Solve[x^9 == 1, x], Point[{Re[#], Im[#]}] &];
Show[Graphics[{PointSize[.018], pts}],
    AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> True];
```

Someone who has patience enough might want to add the plots.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy solution

```
s = Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y}];
x1 = x /. s[[1, 1]];
y1 = y /. s[[1, 2]];
x2 = x /. s[[2, 1]];
y2 = y /. s[[2, 2]];
```

We can verify with

```
MatrixForm[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]
```

The output looks like

[image: assign]

For reference, please look at [assign](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505).

Comment: Correct but seems to duplicate parts of earlier answers.

Comment: Also requires knowing the structure of the solution set. The outcome should not depend on whether `Solve`orders `y` results before or after `x`. Here it does though, and that's not good at all.

Comment: It is different, I used replacement with variables instead of direct assignment.

Comment: As for requirement of knowing the structure, you have to know the structure before you do the assignment, as Mathematica is not showing the solutions in a particular order, which is a pain for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
In[9051]:= sol = 
 Solve[y^2 == 13 x + 17 && y == 193 x + 29, {x, y, x, y}] /. 
  Rule -> Set

Out[9051]= {{(-11181 - Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 
  1/386 (13 - Sqrt[2242057])}, {(-11181 + Sqrt[2242057])/74498, 
  1/386 (13 + Sqrt[2242057])}}

 In[9055]:= x1 = sol[[1, 1]]

 Out[9055]= (-11181 - Sqrt[2242057])/74498

 In[9056]:= y1 = sol[[1, 2]]

Out[9056]= 1/386 (13 - Sqrt[2242057])

In[9057]:= x2 = sol[[2, 1]]

Out[9057]= (-11181 + Sqrt[2242057])/74498

In[9058]:= y2 = sol[[2, 2]]

Out[9058]= 1/386 (13 + Sqrt[2242057])
```