# FindRoot Infinite expression 1/0 encountered error

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I have 1 equation in 1 variable, which when I use `Plot`, looks like this:

```
i = 9
Plot[ A1[[i]]*(92)^(-1.7049946543060777) + B1[[i]]*(92)^(2.9716613209727445)-   
      c1[[i]]*80/0.057 + 65.89077138196083`, {H1S, 125, 135}, AxesOrigin -> {125, 0}]
```

[image]

Where,

```
 A1[[9]]= -0.097752 H1S^2.70499-1.74292 H1S^4.67666 (-((0.213828 (-((1.70499 
           (106.316-  0.166667 H1S))/H1S^2.70499)+0.166667/H1S^1.70499))/H1S^0.266667)
          +(511.685 (-(0.0311244-80/H1S^1.70499) (685034./H1S^1.70499-0.000448489 H1S^2.97166)
          +(0.0358792-71./H1S^1.70499) (877653./H1S^1.70499-0.000389055 H1S^2.97166)))/
           (H1S^2.97166 (-(-0.662221+1702.13/H1S^1.70499)(685034./H1S^1.70499
                                                        -0.000448489 H1S^2.97166)
         +(-0.763386+1702.13/H1S^1.70499) (877653./H1S^1.70499-0.000389055 H1S^2.97166))));

B1[[9]]= (0.213828 (-((1.70499 (106.316-0.166667 H1S))/H1S^2.70499)
          +0.166667/H1S^1.70499))/H1S^0.266667-(511.685 (-(0.0311244-80/H1S^1.70499) 
          (685034./H1S^1.70499-0.000448489 H1S^2.97166)+(0.0358792-71./H1S^1.70499) 
          (877653./H1S^1.70499-0.000389055 H1S^2.97166)))/(H1S^2.97166 
          (-(-0.662221+1702.13/H1S^1.70499) (685034./H1S^1.70499-0.000448489 H1S^2.97166)
          +(-0.763386+1702.13/H1S^1.70499) (877653./H1S^1.70499-0.000389055 H1S^2.97166)));

c1[[9]]= -((-(0.0311244-80/H1S^1.70499) (685034./H1S^1.70499-0.000448489 H1S^2.97166)
            +(0.0358792-71./H1S^1.70499) (877653./H1S^1.70499-0.000389055 H1S^2.97166))/
          (-(-0.662221+1702.13/H1S^1.70499) (685034./H1S^1.70499-0.000448489 H1S^2.97166)
         +(-0.763386+1702.13/H1S^1.70499) (877653./H1S^1.70499-0.000389055 H1S^2.97166)));
```

But when I use `FindRoot` to get the same solution,

```
i = 9;
FindRoot[  A1[[i]]*(92)^(-1.7049946543060777) + B1[[i]]*(92)^(2.9716613209727445)
         - c1[[i]]*80/0.057 + 65.89077138196083` == 0, {H1S, 125, 120, 135}]
```

I get two "things" and the messages :

- Infinite expression 1/0 encountered
- Further output of Power::Infy will be supressed during this this calculation

and then it spits out what looks like the right solution if `Plot` is to be trusted

```
{H1S -> 128.907}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can solve this without the error messages? If the expressions was going to `Infinity` then it should show up on the `Plot` but the `Plot` looks well behaved. Perhaps some derivative is going to infinity during the `FindRoot` process. I have tried other methods specified in the "More Information" : `"Brent"` and `"Secant"` but am getting the same errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining your functions like you did

```
A1[[9]] = -0.097752 H1S^2.70499 - ... + (-0.763386 + 1702.13/H1S^1.70499) 
                                        (877653./H1S^1.70499 - 0.000389055 H1S^2.97166))
```

one gets :

> ```
> Set::noval: Symbol A1 in part assignment does not have an immediate value. >>
> ```

This issue comes from an the fact that you use an immediate assignment to `A1[[9]]` see ([`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html?q=Part&lang=en)) while `A1` hasn't been defined. You could have assigned to `A1[[9]]` if you had evaluated e.g.

```
A1 = Table[0, {9}];
```

then you can do e.g.

```
A1[[9]] = 1;
A1
```

> ```
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
> ```

A more appropriate way is to define a function using `SetDelayed` to `A1[9, H1S_]`  i.e. `lhs := rhs`  delayed assignment where rhs is reevaluated every time it is used, i.e defining  `A1`, `B1`, `c1` , use e.g. :

```
A1[9, H1S_] :=  formula for A1[[9]]
B1[9, H1S_] :=  formula for B1[[9]]
c1[9, H1S_] :=  formula for c1[[9]]
```

then `FindRoot` returns the expected result without any (error) messages generated :

```
FindRoot[ A1[9, H1S]*(92)^(-1.7049946543060777) + B1[9, H1S]*(92)^(2.9716613209727445)
         -c1[9, H1S]*80/0.057 + 65.89077138196083` == 0, {H1S, 125, 120, 135}]
```

> ```
> {H1S -> 128.903}
> ```

You can plot the graph of this function the same way :

```
Plot[ A1[9, H1S]*(92)^(-1.7049946543060777) + B1[9, H1S]*(92)^(2.9716613209727445)
     -c1[9, H1S]*80/0.057 + 65.89077138196083`, {H1S, 125, 135}, AxesOrigin -> {125, 0}]
```

Comment: Hi Artes, Thanks for responding. The thing is that I have 10 variables, $\{x_a,..,x_j\}$ and for each of those variables I have say 60 pieces of data. So $x_a = \{xa_1,xa_2,..,xa_{60}\}$. Now $A1 = f(x_a,..,x_j,H1S)$ and same for B1 and c1. Now for each 10-tuple of data from the x's ,  I want to find a H1S that solves my non-linear equation and ultimately I want to wind up with 60 values of H1S. How should I define my A1s etc so I can Import the data on $\{x_a,..,x_j\}$ and just do all my FindRoots in a Table and get 60 values of H1S?

Comment: contd.. In my original question, I simply typed in the values of $x_{a9},..,x_{j9}$ when $i=9$ so it looked like A1, B1 etc were only functions of H1S.

Comment: @Amatya It seems you could use `Array`, see e.g. this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables/6670#6670, if this is not quite clear for you how to proceed you should better ask another question (more precise) for a detailed answer. It is not so easy to do it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Artes. I will read that and if I still don't get it then I will ask a separate question about data structures.