# Problems with FindMinimum for Constrained Optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to define a simple optimization problem, arising from the discretization of a simple Optimal Control problem.

The problem that results is essentially linear, with bilinearities only appearing in some equality constraints.  The problem is not big and should be solvable by `FindMinimum`.

However I get the following message:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>  
Min::nord: Invalid comparison with ComplexInfinity attempted. >>  
FindMinimum::conv: Interior point method fails to converge. >>
```

I note that the constraints do not contain divisions at all, and the objective is totally linear.

The complete model is given below:

> Simple car problem
>   $\begin{align*}\frac{dv}{dt} &= u\\ \frac{dx}{dt} &= v\end{align*}$
>   $x(0)=0,\quad v(0)=0,\quad x(t_f)=300,\quad v(t_f)=0, \qquad \text{minimize } t_f$.
>    $-2 \leq u\leq +1$.

```
In[51]:= (* try to define the car problem directly below *)
(* v is velocity and x is distance, h is the stepsizes, u are the controls *)

nsteps = 10;

vlist = Table[v[i], {i, 0, nsteps}]

Out[52]= {v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5], v[6], v[7], v[8], v[9], v[10]}

In[53]:= xlist = Table[x[i], {i, 0, nsteps}]

Out[53]= {x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10]}

In[54]:= hlist = Table[h[i], {i, 1, nsteps}]

Out[54]= {h[1], h[2], h[3], h[4], h[5], h[6], h[7], h[8], h[9], h[10]}

In[55]:= ulist = Table[u[i], {i, 1, nsteps}]

Out[55]= {u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4], u[5], u[6], u[7], u[8], u[9], u[10]}

In[56]:= varslist = Join[vlist, xlist, hlist, ulist]

Out[56]= {v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5], v[6], v[7], v[8], v[9], v[10], x[0], 
 x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10], h[1], h[2], 
 h[3], h[4], h[5], h[6], h[7], h[8], h[9], h[10], u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4], 
 u[5], u[6], u[7], u[8], u[9], u[10]}

In[57]:= obj0 = Sum[h[i], {i, 1, nsteps}]

Out[57]= h[1] + h[2] + h[3] + h[4] + h[5] + h[6] + h[7] + h[8] + h[9] + h[10]

In[58]:= odes = Flatten[
  Table[{x[i] - x[i - 1] == v[i]*h[i], v[i] - v[i - 1] == h[i]*u[i]}, {i, 1, 
    nsteps}]]

Out[58]= {-x[0] + x[1] == h[1] v[1], -v[0] + v[1] == h[1] u[1], -x[1] + x[2] == 
  h[2] v[2], -v[1] + v[2] == h[2] u[2], -x[2] + x[3] == 
  h[3] v[3], -v[2] + v[3] == h[3] u[3], -x[3] + x[4] == 
  h[4] v[4], -v[3] + v[4] == h[4] u[4], -x[4] + x[5] == 
  h[5] v[5], -v[4] + v[5] == h[5] u[5], -x[5] + x[6] == 
  h[6] v[6], -v[5] + v[6] == h[6] u[6], -x[6] + x[7] == 
  h[7] v[7], -v[6] + v[7] == h[7] u[7], -x[7] + x[8] == 
  h[8] v[8], -v[7] + v[8] == h[8] u[8], -x[8] + x[9] == 
  h[9] v[9], -v[8] + v[9] == h[9] u[9], -x[9] + x[10] == 
  h[10] v[10], -v[9] + v[10] == h[10] u[10]}

In[59]:= ubounds = Flatten[Table[{u[i] <= 1.0, u[i] >= -2.0}, {i, 1, nsteps}]]

Out[59]= {u[1] <= 1., u[1] >= -2., u[2] <= 1., u[2] >= -2., u[3] <= 1., u[3] >= -2., 
 u[4] <= 1., u[4] >= -2., u[5] <= 1., u[5] >= -2., u[6] <= 1., u[6] >= -2., 
 u[7] <= 1., u[7] >= -2., u[8] <= 1., u[8] >= -2., u[9] <= 1., u[9] >= -2., 
 u[10] <= 1., u[10] >= -2.}

In[60]:= hbounds = Flatten[Table[{h[i] <= 100.0, h[i] >= 0.01}, {i, 1, nsteps}]]

Out[60]= {h[1] <= 100., h[1] >= 0.01, h[2] <= 100., h[2] >= 0.01, h[3] <= 100., 
 h[3] >= 0.01, h[4] <= 100., h[4] >= 0.01, h[5] <= 100., h[5] >= 0.01, 
 h[6] <= 100., h[6] >= 0.01, h[7] <= 100., h[7] >= 0.01, h[8] <= 100., 
 h[8] >= 0.01, h[9] <= 100., h[9] >= 0.01, h[10] <= 100., h[10] >= 0.01}

In[61]:= boundary = {x[0] == 0.0, v[0] == 0.0, v[nsteps] == 0.0, x[nsteps] == 300.0}

Out[61]= {x[0] == 0., v[0] == 0., v[10] == 0., x[10] == 300.}

In[62]:= constr0 = Join[odes, ubounds, hbounds, boundary]

Out[62]= {-x[0] + x[1] == h[1] v[1], -v[0] + v[1] == h[1] u[1], -x[1] + x[2] == 
  h[2] v[2], -v[1] + v[2] == h[2] u[2], -x[2] + x[3] == 
  h[3] v[3], -v[2] + v[3] == h[3] u[3], -x[3] + x[4] == 
  h[4] v[4], -v[3] + v[4] == h[4] u[4], -x[4] + x[5] == 
  h[5] v[5], -v[4] + v[5] == h[5] u[5], -x[5] + x[6] == 
  h[6] v[6], -v[5] + v[6] == h[6] u[6], -x[6] + x[7] == 
  h[7] v[7], -v[6] + v[7] == h[7] u[7], -x[7] + x[8] == 
  h[8] v[8], -v[7] + v[8] == h[8] u[8], -x[8] + x[9] == 
  h[9] v[9], -v[8] + v[9] == h[9] u[9], -x[9] + x[10] == 
  h[10] v[10], -v[9] + v[10] == h[10] u[10], u[1] <= 1., u[1] >= -2., 
 u[2] <= 1., u[2] >= -2., u[3] <= 1., u[3] >= -2., u[4] <= 1., u[4] >= -2., 
 u[5] <= 1., u[5] >= -2., u[6] <= 1., u[6] >= -2., u[7] <= 1., u[7] >= -2., 
 u[8] <= 1., u[8] >= -2., u[9] <= 1., u[9] >= -2., u[10] <= 1., u[10] >= -2., 
 h[1] <= 100., h[1] >= 0.01, h[2] <= 100., h[2] >= 0.01, h[3] <= 100., 
 h[3] >= 0.01, h[4] <= 100., h[4] >= 0.01, h[5] <= 100., h[5] >= 0.01, 
 h[6] <= 100., h[6] >= 0.01, h[7] <= 100., h[7] >= 0.01, h[8] <= 100., 
 h[8] >= 0.01, h[9] <= 100., h[9] >= 0.01, h[10] <= 100., h[10] >= 0.01, 
 x[0] == 0., v[0] == 0., v[10] == 0., x[10] == 300.}

In[63]:= nvars0 = Dimensions[varslist][[1]]

Out[63]= 42

In[64]:= vars0 = Transpose[{varslist, Table[Random[Real, {0., 1.}], {nvars0}]}]

Out[64]= {{v[0], 0.994273}, {v[1], 0.132455}, {v[2], 0.7492}, {v[3], 0.422551}, {v[4], 
  0.3127}, {v[5], 0.734046}, {v[6], 0.386862}, {v[7], 0.95813}, {v[8], 
  0.319134}, {v[9], 0.0195711}, {v[10], 0.547824}, {x[0], 0.126578}, {x[1], 
  0.91368}, {x[2], 0.385664}, {x[3], 0.195437}, {x[4], 0.589594}, {x[5], 
  0.369296}, {x[6], 0.437719}, {x[7], 0.205286}, {x[8], 0.210231}, {x[9], 
  0.145847}, {x[10], 0.225091}, {h[1], 0.572089}, {h[2], 0.681713}, {h[3], 
  0.151574}, {h[4], 0.0926365}, {h[5], 0.822889}, {h[6], 0.259161}, {h[7], 
  0.838874}, {h[8], 0.35859}, {h[9], 0.436027}, {h[10], 0.301031}, {u[1], 
  0.51974}, {u[2], 0.339019}, {u[3], 0.888204}, {u[4], 0.174453}, {u[5], 
  0.60606}, {u[6], 0.953355}, {u[7], 0.692767}, {u[8], 0.584859}, {u[9], 
  0.236764}, {u[10], 0.515636}}

In[65]:= constr0 = Apply[And, constr0]

Out[65]= -x[0] + x[1] == h[1] v[1] && -v[0] + v[1] == h[1] u[1] && -x[1] + x[2] == 
  h[2] v[2] && -v[1] + v[2] == h[2] u[2] && -x[2] + x[3] == 
  h[3] v[3] && -v[2] + v[3] == h[3] u[3] && -x[3] + x[4] == 
  h[4] v[4] && -v[3] + v[4] == h[4] u[4] && -x[4] + x[5] == 
  h[5] v[5] && -v[4] + v[5] == h[5] u[5] && -x[5] + x[6] == 
  h[6] v[6] && -v[5] + v[6] == h[6] u[6] && -x[6] + x[7] == 
  h[7] v[7] && -v[6] + v[7] == h[7] u[7] && -x[7] + x[8] == 
  h[8] v[8] && -v[7] + v[8] == h[8] u[8] && -x[8] + x[9] == 
  h[9] v[9] && -v[8] + v[9] == h[9] u[9] && -x[9] + x[10] == 
  h[10] v[10] && -v[9] + v[10] == h[10] u[10] && u[1] <= 1. && u[1] >= -2. && 
 u[2] <= 1. && u[2] >= -2. && u[3] <= 1. && u[3] >= -2. && u[4] <= 1. && 
 u[4] >= -2. && u[5] <= 1. && u[5] >= -2. && u[6] <= 1. && u[6] >= -2. && 
 u[7] <= 1. && u[7] >= -2. && u[8] <= 1. && u[8] >= -2. && u[9] <= 1. && 
 u[9] >= -2. && u[10] <= 1. && u[10] >= -2. && h[1] <= 100. && h[1] >= 0.01 &&
  h[2] <= 100. && h[2] >= 0.01 && h[3] <= 100. && h[3] >= 0.01 && 
 h[4] <= 100. && h[4] >= 0.01 && h[5] <= 100. && h[5] >= 0.01 && 
 h[6] <= 100. && h[6] >= 0.01 && h[7] <= 100. && h[7] >= 0.01 && 
 h[8] <= 100. && h[8] >= 0.01 && h[9] <= 100. && h[9] >= 0.01 && 
 h[10] <= 100. && h[10] >= 0.01 && x[0] == 0. && v[0] == 0. && v[10] == 0. && 
 x[10] == 300.

In[66]:= FindMinimum[
 {obj0, constr0}, vars0, Method -> "InteriorPoint"
 ]

During evaluation of In[66]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[66]:= Min::nord: Invalid comparison with ComplexInfinity attempted. >>

During evaluation of In[66]:= FindMinimum::conv: Interior point method fails to converge. >>

Out[66]= FindMinimum[{obj0, constr0}, vars0, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
```

Comment: Not sure but it seems that your problem is related to a similar one which was answered here : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/findroot-infinite-expression-1-0-encountered-error/10363#10363.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but this might help a little:

Your system can be written as

$$
\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2} = u(x),
$$

and with $x(0) = 0$, $x(t_f) = 300$ it has as solution [1]

$$
x(t) = \frac{300 t}{t_f} + \frac{t-t_f}{t_f}\int_0^t s u(s) ds + \frac{t}{t_f}\int_t^{t_f} (s-t_f)u(s) ds,
$$

as one can verify with *MMA*

```
x[t_, tf_] := 300 t/tf + (t - tf)/tf Integrate[s u[s], {s, 0, t}] + 
    t/tf Integrate[(s - tf) u[s], {s, t, tf}]

Simplify@{x[0, tf], x[tf, tf], D[x[t, tf], {t, 2}]}

(* {0, 300, u[t]} *)
```

Then

$$
v(t_f) = \frac{1}{t_f}\left(300 + \int_0^{t_f} s u(s) ds \right)
$$

And hence, the problem can be rephrased as

> Find the minimum of $f(t_f) = t_f$ subject to the constraint
>   $$
> 0 = \left(300 + \int_0^{t_f} s u(s) ds \right)
> $$

Now, I don't fully understand what you are doing and I don't know much on control theory, but maybe you can try to solve the problem using a trapezoidal approximation along with your random variables.

[1] Friedman B, *Principles and Techniques of Applied Mathematics*, Wiley & Sons, 1956.