# How to extract Solve results as variables

Tags: equation-solving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

In the following example:

```
Clear[g1, z1, a, g2, z2]
sa = Solve[ g1 == 1 + l z1/(z1^2 + a), a]
sb = Solve[ g2 == 1 - l z2/(z2^2 + b), b] /. z2 -> z1 + l
```

This gives me solutions for `a` and `b` that are in the form

```
{{ a -> astuff }}
{{ b -> bstuff }}
```

I want to use this result in a secondary computation, and did so by cut and pasting from the `Solve[]` results like so

```
 Solve[ astuff == bstuff, z1 ]
```

How can I just extract those results without cut and pasting?  I don't like the cut and paste dependency since I'd have to redo it all if I make any sort of correction to the first couple identities.

Comment: You can use `Part` to extract the relevant bits.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`):

```
Clear[g1, z1, a, g2, z2]
sa = Solve[g1 == 1 + l z1/(z1^2 + a), a]
sb = Solve[g2 == 1 - l z2/(z2^2 + b), b] /. z2 -> z1 + l

Solve[(a /. sa[[1]]) == (b /. sb[[1]]), z1]
```

Here the /. command is used to manipulate the expressions a and b according to the rules given by sa and sb.