# How to convert the expression '{a->a0, b->b0}' to the expression 'a=a0; b=b0'?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, rule

How to convert the expression '{a->a0, b->b0}' to the expression 'a=a0; b=b0'?
I think this is a common question and do not know if someone has asked it before. Any help or suggestion will be appreiated!

Comment: @Nasser Thanks! I update the question.

Comment: It think this is arguably a duplicate of:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121 -- if this question is closed I will delete my answer below.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're welcome :D :D

Comment: You can `Apply` `Set` at level one:  `Set @@@ {a -> a0, b -> b0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
r = {a -> a0, b -> b0}
r /. Rule -> Set
```

Then now `a` and `b` will be set automatically

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will not see the `a=a0`, since this is done on the fly, and M will assign `a` to `a0`.