# Trouble to assign solution of differential equation to a function

Tags: differential-equations, assignment

I have written a function to Solve the following differential equation  [image] 
where the number n (called in my code Nphoton) is a variable.
Nevertheless I have troubles to assign the solutions `sol` of the differential equation to functions `funCa0`, `funCb0` ... 
The code

```
Do[
    ToExpression[
      "fun" <> ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "=Evaluate[" <> 
       ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "[t]/.sol][[1]]"];
    , {i, 1, Length[vec]}
    ];
```

returns the error message

`ReplaceAll::reps: {sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>`

I do not understand this message, what is wrong with `sol`?

My entire function is (it can be run simply by pasting it):

```
funoscillation[Nphoton_, intialAtomState_, NphotonInitial_, g0_, g1_,wSP_, w0_] := 
  Module[{g0li, g1li, Delta, Omega, vec, funvec, eqns, sol, funPlot, 
    solReal, end},
   g0li = Conjugate[g0];
   g1li = Conjugate[g1];

   Delta = wSP - w0;
   Omega = wSP + w0;

   If[Nphoton - 1 < NphotonInitial, 
    Print["ATTENTION: no intial state provided"]; Goto[end];];
   vec = {};
   funvec = {};
Do[
  AppendTo[vec, ToExpression[StringJoin["Ca", ToString[i]]]];
  AppendTo[funvec, 
   ToExpression[StringJoin["funCa", ToString[i]]]]
  , {i, 0,    Nphoton - 1}];
Do[
  AppendTo[vec, ToExpression[StringJoin["Cb", ToString[i]]]];
  AppendTo[funvec, 
   ToExpression[StringJoin["funCb", ToString[i]]]]
  , {i, 0,    Nphoton - 1}];

   eqns = {};
   Do[
    If[i == 0,
     AppendTo[eqns, 
      ToExpression[
       "Ca" <> ToString[i] <> "'[t]==-I " <> ToString[g0] <> 
        " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
        "+1] Exp[-I " <> ToString[Delta] <> " t] Cb" <> 
        ToString[i + 1] <> "[t]"]];

        AppendTo[eqns, 
          ToExpression[

       "Cb" <> ToString[i] <> "'[t]==-I " <> ToString[g1] <> 
        " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
              "+1] Exp[-I " <> ToString[Omega] <> " t] Ca" <> 
        ToString[i + 1] <> "[t]"]];
        ];

      If[i > 0 && i < Nphoton - 1,
        AppendTo[eqns, 
          ToExpression[

       "Ca" <> ToString[i] <> "'[t]==-I " <> ToString[g0] <> 
        " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
              "+1] Exp[-I " <> ToString[Delta] <> " t] Cb" <> 
        ToString[i + 1] <> 
              "[t]-I " <> ToString[g1li] <> " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
        "] Exp[I " <> ToString[Omega] <> " t] Cb" <> 
              ToString[i - 1] <> "[t]"]];

        AppendTo[eqns, 
          ToExpression[

       "Cb" <> ToString[i] <> "'[t]==-I " <> ToString[g1] <> 
        " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
              "+1] Exp[-I " <> ToString[Omega] <> " t] Ca" <> 
        ToString[i + 1] <> 
              "[t]-I " <> ToString[g0li] <> " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
        "] Exp[I " <> ToString[Delta] <> " t] Ca" <> 
              ToString[i - 1] <> "[t]"]];
        ];

      If[i == Nphoton - 1,
        AppendTo[eqns, 
          ToExpression[

       "Ca" <> ToString[i] <> "'[t]==-I " <> ToString[g1li] <> 
        " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
              "] Exp[I " <> ToString[Omega] <> " t] Cb" <> 
        ToString[i - 1] <> "[t]"]];

        AppendTo[eqns, 
          ToExpression[

       "Cb" <> ToString[i] <> "'[t]==-I " <> ToString[g0li] <> 
        " Sqrt[" <> ToString[i] <> 
              "] Exp[I " <> ToString[Delta] <> " t] Ca" <> 
        ToString[i - 1] <> "[t]"]];
        ];

      , {i, 0, Nphoton - 1}];


    Do[

      If[i == NphotonInitial ,
      If[intialAtomState == b,
       AppendTo[eqns, ToExpression["Ca" <> ToString[i] <> "[0]==0"]];
       AppendTo[eqns, ToExpression["Cb" <> ToString[i] <> "[0]==1"]];];
      If[intialAtomState == a,
       AppendTo[eqns, 
        ToExpression["Ca" <> ToString[i] <> "[0]==1"]];    
       AppendTo[eqns, ToExpression["Cb" <> ToString[i] <> "[0]==0"]];],

      AppendTo[eqns, ToExpression["Ca" <> ToString[i] <> "[0]==0"]];
      AppendTo[eqns, ToExpression["Cb" <> ToString[i] <> "[0]==0"]];
          ];

      , {i, 0, Nphoton - 1}];

   sol = NDSolve[eqns, vec, {t, 0, 10}];

   Do[
    ToExpression[
      "fun" <> ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "=Evaluate[" <> 
       ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "[t]/.sol][[1]]"];
    , {i, 1, Length[vec]}
    ];

   Print[funvec];
   Print[funCa0];
   funPlot = Abs[(# & /@ funvec)]^2;

   Plot[funPlot, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> vec, PlotRange -> All]

   ];

funoscillation[2, a, 1, 1*0, 1, 2 Pi, 2 Pi]
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read for what is probably a rather simple question.  Could you try to provide a more minimal example?  Also, have you read this?: [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669)

Comment: Also, please see this question as well as the five links in the comment below it: [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511) -- you should not have to use `ToString` and `ToExpression` very often; here they are clearly being "abused" for a purpose that would be better served with a different method.

Comment: This is indeed a long code but the first part is only to define the differential equation `eqns` to solve. You can start reading almost at the end to understand my problem: from `sol = NDSolve[eqns, vec, {t, 0, 10}];` (the last ten lines)

Comment: So why not use a shorter example, e.g. `sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]^2, y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t]^3, x[0] == y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 20}]` (from the documentation) unless it lacks a certain property of your actual code?

Comment: Yes it is different. I edited my post. The problem comes from the fact that the number of differential equations to solve is not fixed.

Comment: I get the error "ReplaceAll::reps: {sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>", which would be helpful to include in the question.  Such an error ought to be investigated, and it is a strong hint to experienced users what to look for.  Not everyone is going to paste your code into *M* and see what happens.  Having a hint like that in the question might encourage others to investigate, which is what you want to do.  Also, if you were to put `Print` statements between the `Do` loops, you could localize the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. I erase the `Print` statements before posting, next time I will conserve them.

Answer (score 3):

I realize from the idiomatic way this program was written that *Mathematica* is not a language you're very familiar with yet, at least not with the efficient and readable ways *Mathematica* can address your project.  I won't try to suggest every possible improvement but focus on the specific problem of getting the functions you want into the `Plot`.

The following does not work because the string `"sol"` is converted to `` Global`sol `` and does not match the `Module` variable `sol`, which is localized in the form `sol$nnn` where `nnn` is some integer you don't really have control over.  The other problem is that `funvec` is not updated here, which is what I assumed you wanted to have happen.  (`funvec` has the value `{}` when you try to construct `funPlot` at the end.)  Instead, different variables are created and never used.

```
Do[ToExpression[
    "fun" <> ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "=Evaluate[" <> 
     ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "[t]/.sol][[1]]"];, {i, 1, Length[vec]}];
```

I would advise a different approach. (*Edit: fixed typos/misunderstandings of OP's code.*)

```
funvec = Flatten@
     Table[ToExpression[pre <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, Nphoton - 1}, {pre, {"Ca", "Cb"}}];

funPlot = Abs[Through[funvec[t]] /. sol]^2;

Plot[funPlot, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> funvec, PlotRange -> All, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(`Ca0[t]` and `Cb1[t]` seem to be identically zero.)

In the above, `funvec` is the list of symbols `{Ca0, Cb0, Ca1, Cb1}`.  You could probably use this elsewhere in the code.

Theoretically one could use `Block[{sol}, ...]` instead of `Module` for the variable `sol`, and the `Do` loop would evaluate properly, if it created the list `funvec`.  Note that your `Do` loops are used to create lists.  This is usually done with [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) in the form I used above for `funvec`.  ([`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html) is not always necessary.)

Comment: I want to assign a function to every solution of my differential equation (Ca0,Cb0,...). This is what I wanted to do with the code `  Do[
    ToExpression[
      "fun" <> ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "=Evaluate[" <> 
       ToString[vec[[i]]] <> "[t]/.sol][[1]]"];
    , {i, 1, Length[vec]}
    ];`. Your code is not doing it

Comment: I have edited my code so now `funvec` is well defined. But the problem comes from `sol`

Comment: @lambertmular Quite so: The problem with `sol` is described in my answer.  Re first comment:  Your code doesn't work, so it was hard to figure out what to do with it.  It's a very idiomatic way to program *Mathematica*.  You can get the `InterpolatingFunctions` with `{funCa0, funCb0,...} = funvec /. First[sol]`, constructing the LHS as you will.  Your main problem is using `sol` in a string with `ToExpression`, when `sol` is `Module` variable.