# Export array data into a file

Tags: files-and-directories, list-manipulation, writing

I tried to solve some equation for different values of parameter t and put results into array. Then I wanted to write this data into a txt-file. So i did it with `Write` function. But strings in this file look like:

```
{{y -> -300.339}}
```

Are there some parameters of `Write` function for numbers (with sign) writing only?

```
Array[f, 1000]

x := 2
z := 1
v := 0.98
T := 10
dt := T/1000

For[i = 0, i < 1000, 
 i++, f[i] = Solve[-T/2 + i*dt - y == Sqrt[x^2 + (z - v*y)^2], y]]
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't help:

```
For[i = 0, i < 1000, 
 i++, { a = Solve[-T/2 + i*dt - y == Sqrt[x^2 + (z - v*y)^2], y], 
  f[i] /. a}]
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  If your results are in the form of `Rule` expressions you will need to convert them to bare numbers.  See for example: [(1616091)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1616091/618728),
[(8355218)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8355218/618728),
[(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121)

Comment: Okay, that's a code. 
`Array[f, 1000]

x := 2
z := 1
v := 0.98
T := 10
dt := T/1000

For[i = 0, i < 1000, 
 i++, f[i] = Solve[-T/2 + i*dt - y == Sqrt[x^2 + (z - v*y)^2], y]]`

I tried this one, but it doesn't help:
`For[i = 0, i < 1000, 
 i++, { a = Solve[-T/2 + i*dt - y == Sqrt[x^2 + (z - v*y)^2], y], 
  f[i] /. a}]`

Comment: Please use the **edit** link below your question to include code examples.

Comment: I posted an answer.  I hope the examples help you.  I am not sure what you intend for `f` so I left it out.  If you wish to save the definition of `f` itself please see:  [(2008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
x := 2
z := 1
v := 0.98
T := 10
dt := T/1000

Table[
 y /. Solve[-T/2 + i*dt - y == Sqrt[x^2 + (z - v*y)^2], y][[1]],
 {i, 0, 999}
]
```

> ```
> {-300.33859829722434`, -299.8391603699061`, -299.3397243096371`, 
>  -298.8402901257249`, . . ., 2.506139642749351`, 2.5124784155139106`}
> ```

You should be able to [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) that as a plain list of numbers.  Be aware that I extract only the first solution, should more than one exist, but I am guessing that is OK.

If you need a table including the `i` values:

```
Table[
 {i, y /. Solve[-T/2 + i*dt - y == Sqrt[x^2 + (z - v*y)^2], y][[1]]},
 {i, 0, 999}
]
```