# Assign the results from a Solve to variable

Tags: equation-solving

I am a new user. I know, that my question was already asked billion times before, for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables), but I still cannot adopt these answers to my problem.
In my problem I am solving the equation and a result I get some number of roots:

```
sol=Solve[x^2-5*x+6==0,x]
```

As a result, I get:

```
{{x->2},{x->3}}
```

Now, I want to create a vector with these solution, without `x->`. I tried to do what was written in the above link, like

```
sol=sol[[All,1,2]]
```

I tried to change the above action. Still I cannot avoid `x->` in my variable `sol`. Once again, the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables) gives a solution to my problem if I solved two equations simultaneously. But I have to solve only one.

Thanks in advance,

Mikhail

Comment: Map[x /. # &, sol]

Comment: @Bill, the `Map[]` isn't actually needed: `x /. sol`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's so easy

Comment: Might I suggest looking at the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html)? The business of using `/.` with `Solve[]` is discussed there, among other things.