# Finding the set of solutions of an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have a very simple problem.

I have an equation `f[x] == 0`, where `f[x_] := x^2-4.` In output, I want to get the set of solutions as `{-2, 2}`, not `{{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}`. How can I obtain that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the two standard ways to do what you ask.

```
Solve[x^2 - 4 == 0, x][[All, 1, 2]]
```

or

```
x /. Solve[x^2 - 4 == 0, x]
```

Both of the above return

> `{-2, 2}`

Comment: Another possibility, just for fun: `Flatten@Values@Solve[x^2 - 4 == 0, x]`. However, my favorite is still the `x /. Solve[...]` idiom.