# Saving DSolve results

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[{u''''[x] == 0, v''''[x] == (1/(a*Sqrt[π]))*Exp[-x^2/a^2], 
        u[0] ==  0, u'[0] == 0,  v''[1] == 0, v'''[1] == 0, u[b/H] == v[b/H],
        u'[b/H] == v'[b/H], u''[b/H] == v''[b/H], u'''[b/H] == v'''[b/H]},
        {u, v}, x]
```

How do I save both these functions from the output separately so I can graph them separately? I thought they would be automatically saved as `u[x], v[x]` but this isn't the case. I also found guides on how to save one function using
    `dsaad[x_] = u[x] /. First @ DSolve` but this doesn't work for 2 functions

Comment: The answer to this question is basically the same as to this post: [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

Comment: @Artes The problem is that those save values, where here I need to save entire functions. Dependent on all the variables.

Comment: It doesn't matter, this way you can save functions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the approach suggested by @m_goldberg but here is another way you can do it.

```
sol = DSolve[...]
ux = FullSimplify[u[x] /. sol][[1]]
vx = FullSimplify[v[x] /. sol][[1]]
```

Remember, for some expressions `FullSimplify` maybe very time consuming. `[[1]]` is to remove the curly brackets around the expression.

In response to OP's comments.

To plot the two solutions, you will need to specify numerical values for the parameters `a`, `b` and `H`. BTW, it is not a good practice to use single capital letters.

To have a plot, I assigned random values for the parameters.

```
Plot[ {ux /. {a -> 5, b -> 2, H -> 1}, vx /. {a -> 5, b -> 2, H -> 1}}, {x, 0, 10}, 
      Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

You can manipulate your plot like this,

```
Manipulate[ Plot[{ux /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, H -> H1}, vx /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, H -> H1}}, 
            {x, 0, 10}], {a1, 1, 5}, {b1, 1, 5}, {H1, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually having troubles getting it to plot. Will try your method and see if it works. I know sometimes Mathematica is fussy

Comment: @KennyB See the edit.

Comment: Ah thanks !! Yeah I know capital letters aren't great. It's a bad habit.
I'm assuming this will work with manipulate plot ?Because that is what I have been doing. If not I really don't mind assigning values.
The ux /. is important ? That's where you are "evaluating" it at right ?

Comment: Also, interestingly, those values for a,b,H should not have resulted in those graphs. You may have found something for me to add to my paper.

Comment: @KennyB I don't know nothing about the physics of these equations, since you haven't provided any. Nevertheless, I am happy that my response is helping you .

Comment: Definitely a big help. We were thrown into the deep end with Mathematica. It's been a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

If you have V10 or later, you can use `DSolveValue` which returns the function rather than rules.

```
{uF, vF} = DSolveValue[...]
```

`Uf and Vf` can be used just any built-in function. For older version of Mathematica, you can use

```
{uF, vF} = DSolve[...][[1, All, 2]]
```

which extracts the functions from the rules and gives the same result as `DSolveValue`.

#### Plotting

```
paraUF[aa_, bb_, h_][x_] = N[uF[x] /. {a -> aa, b -> bb, H -> h}];
paraVF[aa_, bb_, h_][x_] = N[vF[x] /. {a -> aa, b -> bb, H -> h}];
```

```
Plot[paraUF[1, 2, 3][x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: uplot]

```
Plot[paraVF[1, 2, 3][x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: vplot]

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed, now I'm just trying to get the plot working.

Comment: @KennyB. See update on plotting.

Comment: Thank you, these are so useful !!

Comment: @KennyB. I'm happy that you find my answer useful, but I'm surprised that you accepted the other answer.

Comment: (+1)@m_goldberg my answer in essence is yours, because whatever I know about *Mathematica*, I learn it from you guyz. Thankyou

Comment: @m_goldberg Both your answers were extremely useful, if I could select both I would. Due to the fact that I am a complete novice at mathematica, I chose the answer that I understood easier. 

But, don't let that disappoint you. I need to learn mathematica, and every answer no matter how complicated or easy, is something for me to reflect on and use to grow my skills.