# How to Transform Roots into a function

Tags: equation-solving

I'm calculating the roots of a polynomial like B= Roots[A==0,y] where A is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix of interest. This returns equations like:

B[[1]]

y == ...

B[[2]]

y == ...

I'd like to use the roots as functions to derivate, plot and do stuff but B already is an equation like y== [an expression]. I'd like to use that expression as a function to plot it, etc. How can I do it?

For example, if the polynomial were x^2 -a then B would be:

B[[1]]

x==a

B[[2]]

x==-a

Now, I want to define a function like f[a_]:=B[[1]] but that obviusly doesn't work since B is an equation an not the expression.

Comment: Please give a concrete but minimal example.

Comment: I add something at the end... does it help?

Comment: Do you want `f[a_]` or `f[x_]`?

Comment: f[a_]... The roots are written in terms of symbolic variables and I want to use them as functions. But roots gives back equations, not expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we look at what `Roots` returns with `FullForm` (which shows an expression the way a Mathematica evaluator "sees" it, we get, for example,

```
Roots[x^2 - a == 0, x] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Or[
>   Equal[x, Times[Power[-1, Rational[2, 3]], Power[a, Rational[1, 3]]]],  
>   Equal[x, Times[-1, Power[-1, Rational[1, 3]], Power[a, Rational[1, 3]]]], 
>   Equal[x, Power[a, Rational[1, 3]]]]
> ```

Were we to change the head `Or` to `List`, we would have a simple list of `Equal` expressions. From these we could extract the 2nd argument with `Part` (which works with any head, not just `List`) and get the expressions you want.

Here is the code that does what is described above.

```
 (List @@ Roots[x^3 - a == 0, x])[[All, 2]]
```

> `{(-1)^(2/3) a^(1/3), -(-1)^(1/3) a^(1/3), a^(1/3)}`

Answer (score 1):

To make a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) out of an equation `y == f[x1, x2,...]`:

```
Clear[makeFunction];
makeFunction /: makeFunction == expr_ := Function @@ {Variables@expr, expr};
List @@ Roots[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x, EquatedTo -> makeFunction]
(*
  {Function[{a, b, c}, (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)], 
   Function[{a, b, c}, (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)]}
*)
```

The variables will be sorted into canonical order by [`Variables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html).