# How to capture the results of Solve in a variable

Tags: equation-solving

I have equations that I solve using Solve, and I want to perform further calculations on the results. For a simple example:

```
Solve[{x + y == 1, x - y == 0}, {x, y}]
```

This gives the result

```
{{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2}}
```

But x and y are still undefined. How do I capture x and y so that I can perform further calculations?

```
?y
```

This give the null result Global'y

Comment: use `ReplaceAll`:  `{x, y} /. Solve[{x + y == 1, x - y == 0}, {x, y}]`

Comment: possible duplicate: [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6670/125)

Comment: @kglr when I tried your method above, found that x and y are not assigned afterwords. They are still free symbols.

Comment: @nasser, right; `ReplaceAll` does not assign values. You need `{x,y} = {x, y} /. Solve[{x + y == 1, x - y == 0}, {x, y}]. ?y`

Comment: @kglr humm... this still does not work for me. I am using 11.2 on Linux. Please see screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B2LMG.png)

Comment: Oh, found out why, you need a `First@` there, that is all. like this `{x, y} = {x, y} /. First@Solve[{x + y == 1, x - y == 0}, {x, y}]` and now your method works. I think it is also simpler that what I wrote below. I looked at the linked to question, and did not actually see the assignment there being made using Cases and Rule->Set method, which I thought was more logical way to do this also.

Comment: I captured y by using Part and All: y = Part[s[[All, 1, 2]], 1].