# How do I make a function from a solution?

Tags: equation-solving

This expression:

```
FullSimplify[Solve[dx == dL - (1/2) dd, dL]]
```

Gives this solution (I've simplified it for brevity):

$$\left\{\left\{ d_L\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{1+z}}{2+z} \right\}\right\}$$
Which appears to be a 'rule', but now I want to create a function from that rule.  Something like:

F[z_] := $\frac{\sqrt{1+z}}{2+z}$

but with the actual result from the **Solve** function.  I've seen various attempts with the **ReplaceAll** command, but I can't seem to get it to work.  How do I do this?

**EDIT:** I'm reasonably comfortable getting the answer using substitution like in the examples on this question: [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables).  What I can't figure out is how to make a proper Function.

Comment: Maybe this will help: it gives a list of pure `Function`, one for each solution: `sol = Solve[a^2 + z a - 2 == 0, a];
Function[z, #] & /@ Values[sol]`

Comment: @Artes - Not as far as I can see. I see several examples where substitution is used to get an answer, but I don't see any answers that show a function being created.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelE2 - No, that doesn't work.  If you cut-and-paste your text exactly into Mathematica, then try `Function[1024]`, all you get is `1024&`.

Comment: You could define two function in my example, since it has two solutions, with `{F, G} = Function[z, #] & /@ Values[sol]`.  (Tho, you should avoid starting names with a capital, esp. single-letter symbols.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 - That looks more promising.  Let me work on that.

Answer (score 5):

I generally do it this way.

```
{{dL -> Sqrt[1 + z]/(2 + z)}}

f[z_] = dL /. %[[1]]

f[2]
(*Sqrt[3]/4*)
```

Comment: That appears to be the right answer.  Thank you.