# Extract actual result from equivalence

Tags: assignment

When I get a result like this {x -> -0.5 - 0.866025 I}, how do extract just the number: -0.5 - 0.866025 I. I can do this with the .rhs() method in Sagemath but I can't find the function in Mathematica. Tks.

Comment: Related [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

Comment: `x/. {x -> -0.5 - 0.866025 I}` or `Values@{x -> -0.5 - 0.866025 I} // First` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I looked all over for that. Is there a list of the most Useful functions like that one. I can't learn all 50,000 at once, and every tutorial seems to hit different areas. 

Comment: I would take a look at [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) if you haven't already seen it. I had been using Mathematica for some time before I read that post and still found it very useful. I also sometimes like to sort questions by highest voted or most frequent and look through the top posts (and sometimes the bottom ones too out of morbid curiosity).